# I want to program a box that will display raw input in python/pygame

Tags: python, math, input, pygame

I want to create a piece of code that will take any key pressed and print that using a `message_to_screen()` def. I have no idea how to do this and don't really know what to search to find it. Anyone out there that can help?

I am trying to create a maths game that will ask questions and you enter the answer. I currently with my knowledge do not know how to program such a thing and hope for help.

Here's my current code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
grey = (100,100,100)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Major League Mathematics')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS = 30

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 100)
menufont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 80)

def text_objects(text,color,size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "menu":
        textSurface = menufont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace = 0,size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (display_width / 2), (display_height / 2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def input_box():

    for event in pygame.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:




def startScreen():

    menu = True

    while menu:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                menu = False

        gameDisplay.fill(grey)
        message_to_screen("Major League Mathematics", black, -200, "menu")
        message_to_screen("Press Enter to start!", black, 100, "medium")
        pygame.display.update()




def gameLoop():

    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False



    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True




        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("test", black, 0, "medium") 
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()


startScreen()
gameLoop()
```

I wish to use the `input_box()` def as my place to display numbers using `message_to_screen()`.

Please help out, I may need to ask more for this project as I'm just starting to use python and pygame and it is for high school.
Let me know if I need to explain anything.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I check for every letter you can press.
If it is pressed, I add it to my `text` string.
Then I display my text with:

`textimage = basicFont.render(text,True,(0,0,0),(255,255,255))`

`screen.blit(textimage,(0,0))`

You can put your keys pressed loop in a function too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll try it out and let you know if I have any issues